# When trying to Edit a Smart Object in Illustrator, it is completely blank

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, smartobject

I have a graphic in Illustrator and have cut-and-pasted it to a Photoshop window as a Smart Object.  I've done this before and when I need to edit the file, I right click on the Smart Object preview window to the right and click "Edit" and it brings up the file back in Illustrator, where I make my edits.

In this case, however, while the image appears in the thumbnail in Photoshop, when I click "Edit" all that I get is a blank white Illustrator page.  There's no text or graphics...but within this same document, when I've done it in the past for other parts of it, this has worked fine.  Why isn't the Smart Object showing up again and editable in Illustrator?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the art isn't actually white and *that's* causing it to not be seen on Illustrator's white artboard....

Zoom Out in Illustrator...

When Smart Objects are opened in AI via PS... Art isn't *always* located on the actual artboard in Illustrator. So using standard shortcuts such as `Fit Artboard to Window` or `Fit All to Window` won't necessarily zoom out far enough to show the artwork.

Make certain it's just not out of view by zooming out.

(If you do find it, you *can* move it to the artboard so its easier in the future. The move won't effect the SO in Photoshop.)

Comment: Just checking:  This is NOT something that's been copied.  This is what appears in Illustrator when I click "Edit" on the small thumbnail of the Smart Object in Photoshop.  It seems odd that the Smart Object wouldn't have its own sense of where the boundaries are.

Comment: But @Scott, I'll still go see if perhaps this is the solution.  Thank you for taking the time!  :-)

Comment: @user1149499 I understand.. some SOs open in AI with artwork off, or unrelated to the actual artboard in AI.

Comment: And interestingly, despite several days of this same thing occurring, now it's NOT and seems to work as I intended.  So either a bug or perhaps my own unintentional user error.  Not sure.  I'll check when it does appear again if it's a zoom issue.  Again, thank you for your time!